# SQL Dynamic Stored Procedure Feeds View Column

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to dynamically build a View column using a stored procedure.  This works great, as long as my stored procedure parameters are static values, as in this example:

```
CREATE VIEW MyTestView AS SELECT T1.ItemId, T1.BatchId, 
    CAST ((SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([LOCALSERVER], 'EXEC [MyDatabase].dbo.MyStoredProcedure
    ''MyItemId'', ''MyBatchNumber''')) AS NVARCHAR(64)) AS FromStoredProc
    FROM MyTable AS T1
```

However, I need the stored procedure to use inputs from the other table in the query as parameter values in order to bring back useful data for each row.

```
CREATE VIEW MyTestView AS SELECT T1.ItemId, T1.BatchId, 
    CAST ((SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([LOCALSERVER], 'EXEC [MyDatabase].dbo.MyStoredProcedure
    T1.ItemId, T1.BatchId')) AS NVARCHAR(64)) AS FromStoredProc
    FROM MyTable AS T1
```

Is there any way to pass T1's values to the stored procedure as parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I guess due to ambiguity of T1 you were not able to run it

```
  CREATE VIEW MyTestView AS SELECT 
     T1.ItemId, T1.BatchId, 
     CAST ((SELECT * FROM 
  OPENQUERY([LOCALSERVER], 'EXEC 
  [MyDatabase].dbo.MyStoredProcedure
  ItemId, BatchID')) AS NVARCHAR(64)) 
   AS FromStoredProc
   FROM MyTable AS T1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this actually sends "ItemId" and "BatchId" as the parameter values... which is weird, since they are not enclosed in single quotes..

Comment: Does it run without any quotes

Comment: It runs with or without quotes, but it just treats them like values, as if they were in quotes.

Comment: It shouldnt behave that way without quotes as these are stored values should replace on a particular run

Comment: Why you dont have open close brackets in a parameterized procedure